# How to align content from a lump of data from sql to web?

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a text in SQL like: "I want to eat. I'm hungry."

I use ASP.NET MVC to get data from database:

```
@Model.content
```

`@Model.content` is "I want to eat. I'm hungry."

I want to format text to display, for example, it might come down the line:

```
 I want to eat.

 I'm hungry.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you don't prefer saving "\n" in the database, you can just split the entire into an array and loop through each item to display it with breaks. use Split

Something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.content.Split(".")) { @item <br /> }
```

Comment: Thanks karthik for your help! But i have a big content and i don't know how many time i have to down the line.

Comment: Then you can write a loop here. Or, can replace every ". " in the string to ". \n" to achieve line breaks.

Comment: In a view of ASP.Net MVC i can't assign variables so i can't get number of occurrences "." therefore i can't use a loop, and in my language have to use unicode so i can't use text datatypes in sql. I use string datatypes and i can't use \n. Do you have a suggestions fo me? thanks you verry much

Comment: yes. In the view, can you use @Model.content.replace(". ", ". \n")?? (not in sql)

Comment: i have to use nvarchar(MAX) in sql and "\n" can't make it down the line

Comment: so it is my way, just did it

Comment: yeh, i try to show you but , i don't know how i can't comment

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model.tour.ProcessTourVI.Split('/'))
        {
            item
            <br />
        }

Comment: It seems that it does not allow the use of 2 @ in a comment

Comment: So, you did a loop here, which we were discussing at the top. Good that it resolved soon for you :)

Comment: ok, thank you very much but i don't give you a like because i'm newbie, my like can't display

Comment: Its okay. You can put up your own answer for the question and mark it as answer, so that will be useful for anyone coming over here.

Comment: how to mark it as answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. But, the reviewers has put your question on hold. So, you might not be getting that option. So, reframe the question, so that it would be understood by everyone and then see if they unlock your question or not.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it does not confuse anyone coming over here :)

Comment: great! thanks for helped me